# How to modify array on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json

**this is my array in model file,**

```
var genres = [
  "Action",
  "Comedy",
  "Documentary"
];
```

**I need to return(res.send) like this,**

```
 [
      { label: "Action", value: 1 },
      { label: "Comedy", value: 2 },
      { label: "Documentary", value: 3 },
      { label: "Drama", value: 4 }
   ];
```

**I wrote get a request like this,**

```
router.get("/genre", (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let genre = MovieModel.genres;
    res.send(genre);
  } catch (e) {
    return res.send(e.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please just choose an answer to mark this as solved (the tick sign on the left of each answer).

Answer (score 2):

You could use Array.map to compose a new array.

```
router.get("/genre", (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.send(MovieModel.genres.map((genre, index) => { return { label: genre, value: index }; }));
  } catch (e) {
    return res.send(e.message);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const genres = [
  "Action",
  "Comedy",
  "Documentary"
];

const newGenres = genres.map((genre, i) => {
  return (
    { "label": genre, "value": i + 1 }
  )
});

console.log(newGenres);
```

Gives you:

```
[
  { label: "Action", value: 1 },
  { label: "Comedy", value: 2 },
  { label: "Documentary", value: 3 },
  { label: "Drama", value: 4 }
];
```

To return this via `res.send`:

```
router.get("/genre", (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let genres = MovieModel.genres;
    res.send(
      genres.map(
        (genre, i) => { return { "label": genre, "value": i + 1 };
      )
    );
  } catch (e) {
    return res.send(e.message);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**Working well**

```
const arr = ["Action", "Comedy", "Documentary", "Drama"];

arr.map((arrElement, index) => ({ label: arrElement, value: index }));
```

Comment: Won't this set the values to 0, 1, 2, 3 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4?